# JS replace function gives unexpected EOF when user push enter in message

Tags: javascript, django, replace

inside dataTable I'm getting text from Django views, and send it to custom written js replace function for replacing certain characters with our native language alphabets. Works with single line perfectly, but when the user pushes enter inside message it gives unexpected EOF. Here is the code

Html

```
    {% for comment in comments %}

        <tr>
             <td>      {{ comment.id }}      </td>
             <td>    {{ comment.req_id }}    </td>
             <td>    {{ comment.ans_id }}    </td>
             <td> <script>document.write(replace("{{ comment.comment_text }}"));</script> </td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDrUl.png)

JS

```
function replace(x) {
var text = String(x);

var lines = text.split("\n");
var returnedText="";

for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
  returnedText += lines[i].toString().allReplace({'É™': 'ə', 'Ä±': 'ı', 'Ã¶': 'ö', 'Ã¼': 'ü','Ã§': 'ç','Ä°': 'İ','ÄŸ': 'ğ','ÅŸ': 'ş', 'Æ': 'Ə','Åž': 'Ş'});
  returnedText += "\n";
}

return returnedText;
}

String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
var retStr = this;
for (var x in obj) {
    retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
}
return retStr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending string to JS, it is much more worth to use custom tags

```
<td><script>document.write(replace("{{ comment.comment_text }}"));</script></td>
```

can be replaced as:
`<td>{{comment.comment_text|convert_utf8 }}</td>`

## convert_utf8 function

```
@register.filter(name='convert_utf8')
def convert_utf8(value):
    return value.replace(unichr(198),unichr(399)).replace......#several replace
```